# Xunit with Mock in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

**Problem:**

I am new to the Xunit environment with C#. I am writing a unit test for a controller. In my controller, there is a data-adding method like this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddQuestionToCampaign([FromBody] CampaignQuestionsViewModel question, [FromQuery] int campaignId)
{
    try
    {
        //read user Id from Token
        //string headerToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        //string token = headerToken.Split("Bearer ")[1];
        //string Creator = tokenService.GetUserIdFromToken(token);

        var userId = 1;
        string errorText;
        if (campaignId != 0)
        {
            if (question != null)
            {
                CampaignQuestions result = null;
                if (question.AddToQuestionBank)
                {
                    Questions addedQuestion = await questionsService.AddQuestionToBank(question, userId);
                    Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addedQuestion));
                    question.OriginatedQuestionId = addedQuestion.Id;
                    result = await campaignQuestionsService.AddQuestionToCampaign(question, userId, campaignId);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = await campaignQuestionsService.AddQuestionToCampaign(question, userId, campaignId);
                }

                if (result != null)
                {
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorText = string.Format(stringLocalizer[Constants.ErrorCodeString],
                        (int)ErroCodes.InternalServerError,
                        stringLocalizer[Helper.ToEnumString(ErroCodes.InternalServerError)]);

                    return StatusCode(500, errorText);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorText = string.Format(stringLocalizer[Constants.ErrorCodeString],
                (int)ErroCodes.NoQuestionsToAdd,
                stringLocalizer[Helper.ToEnumString(ErroCodes.NoQuestionsToAdd)]);

                return StatusCode(404, errorText);
            }
        }

        errorText = string.Format(stringLocalizer[Constants.ErrorCodeString],
        (int)ErroCodes.SpecifiedCamIdIsNotValid,
        stringLocalizer[Helper.ToEnumString(ErroCodes.SpecifiedCamIdIsNotValid)]);

        return StatusCode(404, errorText);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exceptionData =
            $"Exception occured while adding a Question to the campaign. " +
            $"\nException Data: Message- {ex.Message}; " +
            $"InnerException- {ex.InnerException}; StackTrace- {ex.StackTrace}";

        Console.WriteLine(exceptionData);

        string errorText = string.Format(stringLocalizer[Constants.ErrorCodeString],
                (int)ErroCodes.InternalServerError,
                stringLocalizer[Helper.ToEnumString(ErroCodes.InternalServerError)]);

        return StatusCode(500, errorText);
    }
}
```

So for that, I mock the campaignquestionservice and questions service like this.

```
 var questionServiceMock = new Mock<IQuestionsService>();
  var campaignQuestionServiceMock = new Mock<ICampaignQuestionsService>();

CampaignQuestionsViewModel campaignQuestionsViewModel = new()
{
    ISActive = true,
    QuestionType = QuestionType.ImagePicker,
    ActualAnswer = null,
    Validations = null,
    QuestionSeverity = QuestionSeverity.Medium,
    Points = 1,
    Weight = 0,
    CreatedBy = "1",
    Created = System.DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedBy = null,
    Modified = null,
    QuestionMediaType = 0,
    MediaImages = null,
    MediaUrl = "string",
    NoOfImages = 0,
    BaseTitle = "Title2",
    Title = null,
    SetOfAnswers = null,
    Messages = null,
    BaseLanguage = "en-US",
    SetOfLanguages = null,
    CurrentCampaignReference = "1",
    OriginatedQuestionId = "6194b7f033399f59cbe77160",
    AddToQuestionBank = true,
};

Questions question1 = new()
{
    Id = "6194b7f033399f59cbe77160",
    ISActive = true,
    QuestionType = QuestionType.ImagePicker,
    ActualAnswer = null,
    Validations = null,
    QuestionSeverity = QuestionSeverity.Medium,
    Points = 1,
    Weight = 0,
    CreatedBy = "1",
    Created = System.DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedBy = null,
    Modified = null,
    QuestionMediaType = 0,
    MediaImages = null,
    MediaUrl = "string",
    NoOfImages = 0,
    BaseTitle = "Title2",
    Title = null,
    SetOfAnswers = null,
    Messages = null,
    BaseLanguage = "en-US",
    SetOfLanguages = null,
};

CampaignQuestions campaignQuestion = new()
{
    Id= "619747d91e0d0b03319ccb12",
    ISActive= true,
    QuestionType= QuestionType.ImagePicker,
    ActualAnswer= null,
    Validations= null,
    QuestionSeverity= QuestionSeverity.Medium,
    Points= 1,
    Weight= 0,
    CreatedBy  = "1",
    Created= System.DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedBy=null,
    Modified=null,
    QuestionMediaType= 0,
    MediaImages=null,
    MediaUrl = "string",
    NoOfImages = 0,
    BaseTitle = "Title2",
    Title = null,
    SetOfAnswers = null,
    Messages = null,
    BaseLanguage = "en-US",
    SetOfLanguages = null,
    CurrentCampaignReference= "1",
    OriginatedQuestionId= "6194b7f033399f59cbe77160",
    AddToQuestionBank= true,
};

campaignQuestionServiceMock.Setup(x => x.AddQuestionToCampaign(campaignQuestionsViewModel, It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(campaignQuestion));
questionServiceMock.Setup(x => x.AddQuestionToBank(campaignQuestionsViewModel, It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(question1));

questionsService = questionServiceMock.Object;

campaignQuestionsService = campaignQuestionServiceMock.Object;

tokenService = new TokenService();

stringLocalizer = new Mock<IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();

questionBankIntergrationEventService = new Mock<IQuestionBankIntergrationEventService>();

questionsController = new QuestionsController(questionsService, campaignQuestionsService, stringLocalizer.Object, tokenService, questionBankIntergrationEventService.Object);
```

Then I wrote the unit test like this.

```
[Fact]
public async Task AddQuestionToCampaignTest()
{
    CampaignQuestionsViewModel campaignQuestionsViewModel = new()
    {
        ISActive = true,
        QuestionType = QuestionType.ImagePicker,
        ActualAnswer = null,
        Validations = null,
        QuestionSeverity = QuestionSeverity.Medium,
        Points = 1,
        Weight = 0,
        CreatedBy = "1",
        Created = System.DateTime.Now,
        ModifiedBy = null,
        Modified = null,
        QuestionMediaType = 0,
        MediaImages = null,
        MediaUrl = "string",
        NoOfImages = 0,
        BaseTitle = "Title2",
        Title = null,
        SetOfAnswers = null,
        Messages = null,
        BaseLanguage = "en-US",
        SetOfLanguages = null,
        CurrentCampaignReference = "1",
        OriginatedQuestionId = "6194b7f033399f59cbe77160",
        AddToQuestionBank = true,
    };

    var actionResult = await questionsController.AddQuestionToCampaign(campaignQuestionsViewModel, 1);
    var result = actionResult as ObjectResult;
    if (result.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Assert.Equal(200, result.StatusCode);
    }
    else if (result.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        Assert.Contains("ErrorCode", result.Value.ToString());
    }
    else if (result.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        var code = (int)ErroCodes.InternalServerError;
        Assert.Contains(code.ToString(), result.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

But this test was failed so then when I am debugging I come across that in the controller method code  `Questions addedQuestion = await questionsService.AddQuestionToBank(question, userId);` this line does not return anything for addedQuestion variable It means I do not have to mock the method correctly. Can someone help me to correctly mock this service to return data to it? Thank you.

Comment: Why there is in the mock Task.FromResult(question1)) and not only question1

Comment: Use It.Is<...> for pattern matching inside Setup instead of directly passing arguments.

Comment: Just an idea, try integration test instead of unit test for controllers by using WebApplicationFactory, for more detail 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0
I think It's easier and more logical